# Immunological Genome dataset

Tags: data-request, genome

I'm looking for immunology gene dataset, basically try to see if I can find any data what will include all auto immune disorders (at the gene level).

looking online found that only research labs will provide and basically need to be in enrolled in research in immunology to can have access ...

I just try to explore/research the gene sequence, no looking to read articles about disorders meaning of disorders.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Find these datasets in the ImmGen consortium

http://www.immgen.org/

And resources of the journal Immunity